Part name of this IC - "tC5"
I want to know the part numbers of the components marked as shown in the attached image.


This question is similar to: Part name of this IC - "tC5" "LLA#537" "302" "SNA" "PFKI" "5CTI PSZQ". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Andyaka I told him in the other question that the identification guidelines state that a question should only ask for a single part. So imo the other question should be closed for being too broad and this one should stay open.

Instead of raising a new question he should have modified his original question in my opinion to simplify it nanash1

That isn't even close to the same part one is an sot, the other is a much bigger part

It's a Nexperia BAT54XY quad Schottky diode.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Thank you very much
